# How to group results according to range of datetimes on another table records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`BusinessViews`:

| id | createdAt | businessId | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-19 18:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-19 18:02:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-19 18:05:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-19 18:05:50 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-01-19 18:07:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-01-19 18:08:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-01-19 18:10:00 | 1 | 1 |

`BusinessClients`:

| id | status | createdAt | userId | createdBy | businessId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-19 18:01:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-01-19 18:03:00 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-01-19 18:06:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-01-19 18:07:30 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 2022-01-19 18:09:00 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

The `BusinessViews` is for register the business page views by users and `BusinessClients` for the clients history. To get the count of total page views for `businessId = 1` for example I simply did this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BusinessViews 
WHERE businessId = 1 
GROUP BY businessId

Result: 7
```

But now I want to segment this result to get the count of views made by clients and the count of views made by non-clients users at the moment of view. For that, let me explain the dynamics of `BusinessClients`: with this table users can request to be clients of any business and the business employees can refuse/accept (in case of request) and remove (in case of the user is already a client). If the user has no records in the table it's because he was never a client of the business and if the user has records in the table they can have three types of status:

- `status = 1` means user sent the request to business (If the user
  does not have records yet, this is the only possibility)
- `status = 2` means user request was accepted by a business employee
- `status = 0` if `userId = createdBy` means user leaved the business
  and if `userId != createdBy` means employee refused the request (if previous status = 1) or removed user of the business (if previous status = 2)

Taking that into account, the result I would like to get is:

```
Client views: 2
Non-client views: 5
```

I know I have to work with `BusinessClients.status` and `BusinessClients.createdAt` ranges according to `BusinessViews.createdAt` value. But I'm completely out of ideas on how to do this query. I don't know if I should use left join or subqueries and I can't think of any way to get these results.

What is the correct way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

Explaining the desired result: I have 7 views and I want to know how many of these views came from clients and non-clients users **at the moment of the view** (I'm using only one `userId` to simplify understanding but there may be multiple users registering views in `BusinessViews` table and joining and leaving `BusinessClients` table), so:

- **BusinessView** with `id = 1` was created at 2022-01-19 18:00:00 and at this moment the corresponding user is not a client yet (because he was never a client), so:

> `Client Views: 0` and `Non-client views: 1`.

- **BusinessView** with `id = 2` was created at 2022-01-19 18:02:00 and at this moment the corresponding user is not a client yet again (because the `current status still = 1` at this time and only changed at 2022-01-19 18:03:00 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 2`), so:

> `Client Views: 0` and `Non-client views: 2`.

- **BusinessView** with `id = 3` was created at 2022-01-19 18:05:00 and at this moment the corresponding user is already a client (because `status = 2` was created at 2022-01-19 18:03:00 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 2`) and only changed at 2022-01-19 18:06:00 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 3`), so:

> `Client Views: 1` and `Non-client views: 2`.

- **BusinessView** with `id = 4` same as previous item, so:

> `Client Views: 2` and `Non-client views: 2`.

- **BusinessView** with `id = 5` was created at 2022-01-19 18:07:00 and at this moment the corresponding user is not a client anymore (because `status = 0` was created at 2022-01-19 18:06:00 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 3`) and only changed at 2022-01-19 18:07:30 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 4`), so:

> `Client Views: 2` and `Non-client views: 3`

- **BusinessView** with `id = 6` was created at 2022-01-19 18:08:00 and at this moment the corresponding user still not a client (because `status = 1` was created at 2022-01-19 18:07:30 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 4`) and only changed at 2022-01-19 18:09:00 (**BusinessClient** with `id = 5`), so:

> `Client Views: 2` and `Non-client views: 4`.

- **BusinessView** with `id = 7` same as previous item (the only difference is that this is the last record so far), so

> `Client Views: 2` and `Non-client views: 5`.

The question is: where is the `BusinessViews.createdAt` between the `BusinessClients.createdAt` records and what is the corresponding `BusinessClients.status` for the user at `BusinessViews.createdAt`?

Comment: I cannot understand what the link is between BusinessViews and BusinessClients. You say you expect the client view count to be 2, so which two ids in BusinessClients should match with which two ids in BusinessViews and based on what rules? They all have the same businessId and userId, and none of the createdAt values match.

Comment: I'm not sure about your expected result. Since the `BusinessViews` have 7 rows and `BusinessClients` have 5 rows, it seems like s you're saying that the `Non-client views: 5` comes from `BusinessClients` table, possibly matching `userId` and `businessId` and whatever not match becomes `Client views: 2`. If that's correct, why take `status` into consideration?

Comment: @nnichols I updated the question with more examples

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand your requirement now. I have updated my answer to use LEFT JOIN LATERAL instead of a normal LEFT JOIN. What size are these tables? Are you expecting to run this as a real-time query or just analysis? What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @nnichols currently, the `BusinessViews` has 3502 rows and `BusinessClients` has 5701 rows (they constantly increase). I'm expecting to run as a real-time query for business-owners consult visits whenever they want. Using 8.0.23 version of MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Thank you for adding the explanation of the join.

```
Client views: 2
Non-client views: 5
```

```
WITH BusinessViews (id, createdAt, businessId, userId) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2022-01-19 18:00:00', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2022-01-19 18:02:00', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2022-01-19 18:05:00', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '2022-01-19 18:05:50', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '2022-01-19 18:07:00', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '2022-01-19 18:08:00', 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, '2022-01-19 18:10:00', 1, 1
), BusinessClients (id, status, createdAt, userId, createdBy, businessId) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, '2022-01-19 18:01:00', 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2, '2022-01-19 18:03:00', 1, 2, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 0, '2022-01-19 18:06:00', 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, '2022-01-19 18:07:30', 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 0, '2022-01-19 18:09:00', 1, 2, 1
)
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN bcs.status IS NULL OR bcs.status <> 2 THEN 1 END) 'non-client-views',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN bcs.status = 2 THEN 1 END) 'client-views'
FROM BusinessViews bv
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT status
    FROM BusinessClients bc
    WHERE bc.businessID = bv.businessID
    AND bc.userId = bv.userId
    AND bc.createdAt < bv.createdAt
    ORDER BY bc.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) bcs ON true
WHERE bv.businessId = 1;
```

I have included the CTEs to save others the effort, if they fancy trying this.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh!!! It's exactly what I needed! I had never heard about lateral joins before, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly :

```
SELECT 
   Count(case when bc.id is null end) as client
 , count(case when bc.id is not null end) as non-client 
FROM BusinessViews bv
Left join BusinessClients bc
On bv.businessid = bc.businessid
WHERE bv.businessId = 1 
GROUP BY bv.businessId
```

Comment: That CASE syntax is not valid!

Comment: I updated the question with more information and examples